# Can electrical conduit cross over a gas line?

Tags: conduit, nec

I'm running conduit to my shop for a subpanel.  The conduit coming out of my house crosses over my gas line (see pic).  Is this allowed?  I just put the conduit in and wondered if this will get flagged.  If they can cross, then is there a minimum separation required?  I'm in the US.[image]

Comment: I think a better question would be "how much clearance is required between gas lines and electrical conduit", since they _must_ cross in places...

Comment: @FreeMan Thanks, good point.  I edited to include this part.

Comment: Loosely related: Here's a question about electrical and gas lines crossing, but in an underground situation. https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/61337/95658